# Sum of powers of $z$ with $|z| = 1$, $z \neq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that for $z \neq 1$ with $|z| = 1$ the sequence of partial sums $s_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} z^{k}$ is bounded. I kinda understand the reason why it should happen but I do not see the way to truly prove it. I have tried to reduce the problem looking at real and imaginary parts and the problem is equivalent to prove that the series $S_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \cos(n \alpha) $ is bounded for any real $\alpha$.

Any ideas?

Comment: $\sum z^n$ or $\sum z^k$?

Comment: $z^{k}$, Thanks, I have edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

so
$$|S_n|\leq \frac{1+|z|^{n+1}}{|1-z|}=\frac{2}{|1-z|}=M$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $z \neq 1$, you have $s_n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$. Since $|z| = 1$, you have $|s_n|  \leq  \frac{2}{|z-1|}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Assuming you meant $z^k$ in your definition of $s_n,$ we have $$s_n=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$ for $z\ne1.$ Use triangle inequality to find a bound.